# Pandas dataframe value_counts count same values seperately as unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, dtype

I try to replace the ? in the dataset with the mode of the column.

First I check the unique value in that column by using

```
df['bare_nucleoli'].value_counts()
```

This is the result

```
1     402
10    132
5      30
2      30
3      28
8      21
4      19
?      16
9       9
7       8
6       4
Name: bare_nucleoli, dtype: int64
```

So I decided to change the question mark into NaN first in order to check for the mark in other column

```
import numpy as np
df.replace('?',np.nan, inplace = True)
```

And then change the NaN to the mode of that column, which is 1.

```
df['bare_nucleoli'].fillna(1, inplace = True)
```

The result shows that it changed the NaN value, but it was counted seperately as another unique value like this

```
1     402
10    132
5      30
2      30
3      28
8      21
4      19
1      16
9       9
7       8
6       4
Name: bare_nucleoli, dtype: int64
```

What's the reason behind this and how can I change the value and put it in the same group?

Comment: The answers already provided are likely on the right track with the original values being strings.  You can replace your `.replace()` line with `df['bare_nucleoli'] = pd.to_numeric(df['bare_nucleoli'], errors='coerce')`, which will take care of both converting `?` to `NaN` and converting the entire column to numeric. Then you can run `.fillna()`.

Comment: problem solved! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but if you try df.dtypes, you might find the first column is of object type. Possibly the first is a string '1' instead of a numeric 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a string rather than an integer. You can accomplish your goal much more simply with

```
 bare_nucleoli_mode = df['bare_nucleoli'].mode()
 df['bare_nucleoli'] = df['bare_nucleoli'].replace('?', bare_nucleoli_mode)`.
```

Comment: Note: mode is not always a scalar, so `.mode()` can return a tuple if there is more than one mode (not in this case, it appears).

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
df.loc[df['bare_nucleoli'] == '?'] = 1
df['bare_nucleoli'].value_counts()
```